# ¿Cómo obtener año, mes y día de fecha recibida de POST en Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, date

Tengo el siguiente código en mi **Controller**:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $fecha = $request->fecha;
    $mfecha = $request->fecha->format('m');
    $dfecha = $request->fecha->format('d');
    $afecha = $request->fecha->format('Y');
}
```

Al ejecutar en el explorador me sale el siguiente error:

> **message:** "Call to a member function format() on string"

Quiero obtener el año, mes y día por separado, me podrían ayudar.

Comment: para entender mejor el problema, es necesario que coloque todo el codigo para comprender mejor el poblema

Comment: No sabemos qué tipo de objeto es `$request`... sería de gran ayuda que  escribas un `var_dump($request);` mostrando el resultado mediante una [edición de tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/168258/edit). Es muy probable que `$request` sea un objeto que contenga ya la información que buscas, por eso es importante el `var_dump`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En caso de que tu **Request** este bien y la `fecha` te llegue de forma correcta, el siguiente ejemplo tendria que funcionarte:

Colocas en la cabecera de tu documento `use Carbon\Carbon;` y posteriormente la funcion seria la siguiente:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $fecha = Carbon::parse($request->fecha);
    $mfecha = $fecha->month;
    $dfecha = $fecha->day;
    $afecha = $fecha->year;
}
```

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó su ayuda. Muchas gracias.